# $\|K\|=\max_{j}s_{j}(K)$ for Compact Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, compact-operators, singular-values

Could anyone reference me to a proof of

$$\|K\|=\max_{j}s_{j}(K)$$

$K$ being a compact operator and $s_{j}(K)$ being the singular values of the operator.

I cannot find a proof in the literature.

Comment: Can you find a proof of the singular value decomposition as suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2634716/singular-value-decomposition-of-a-compact-operator-using-matrix-notation)?, using that it seems plausible to prove your assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K:\mathcal{H}_1\to\mathcal{H}_2$ be a compact operators where $\mathcal{H}_j$ are Hilbert spaces. The singular decomposition of $K$ is given by
\begin{align}
K&=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}s_j(K)\,e_j\otimes f_j
\end{align}
where $\{e_j\vert j\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is the orthonormal system of $\mathcal{H}_1$ formed by the eigenvectors of the non-negative self-adjoint operator $K^*K$, $s_j(K)=\sqrt{\lambda_j(K^*K)}$ with $\lambda_j(K^*K)$ the eigenvalues of $K^*K$, and
\begin{align}
f_j&=\begin{cases}s_j(K)^{-1}Ke_j&\text{if }s_j(K)\neq0,\\
0&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}
\end{align}
You can check that $\langle f_j,f_k\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_2}=\delta_{j,k}$. Furthermore,
\begin{align}
K^*K&=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}s_j(K)^2\,e_j\otimes e_j.\tag{$\star$}
\end{align}

Now we compute:
\begin{align}
\|K\|_{\mathcal{H}_1\to\mathcal{H}_2}=\sup_{\|u\|_{\mathcal{H}_1}=1}\|Ku\|_{\mathcal{H}_2}&=\sup_{\|u\|_{\mathcal{H}_1}=1}\sqrt{\langle Ku,Ku\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_2}}\\
&=\sup_{\|u\|_{\mathcal{H}_1}=1}\sqrt{\langle K^*Ku,u\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}}\\
&=\max\{s_j(K)\vert j\in\mathbb{N}\}.
\end{align}
We used the decomposition $(\star)$ for the last equality:
\begin{align}
\forall u=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\langle e_j,u\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}e_j\in\mathcal{H}_1,
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\langle K^*K u,u\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}&=\left\langle\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}s_j(K)^2\,(e_j\otimes e_j)\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\langle e_k,u\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}e_k,\sum_{\ell=0}^{+\infty}\langle e_\ell,u\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}e_\ell\right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}\\
%
&=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}s_j(K)^2\overline{\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\langle e_k,u\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}}\sum_{\ell=0}^{+\infty}\langle e_\ell,u\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}\left\langle(e_j\otimes e_j)e_k,e_\ell\right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}\\
%
&=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}s_j(K)^2\overline{\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\langle e_k,u\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}}\sum_{\ell=0}^{+\infty}\langle e_\ell,u\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}\left\langle\delta_{j,k} e_j,e_\ell\right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}\\
%
&=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}s_j(K)^2\overline{\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\langle e_k,u\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}}\sum_{\ell=0}^{+\infty}\langle e_\ell,u\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}\delta_{j,k}\delta_{j,\ell}\\
%
&=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}s_j(K)^2\left|\langle e_j,u\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}\right|^2\\
%
&\leq\max\{s_j(K)\vert j\in\mathbb{N}\}^2\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\left|\langle e_j,u\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}\right|^2\\
%
&=\max\{s_j(K)\vert j\in\mathbb{N}\}^2\|u\|^2.
\end{align}
It follows that $\|K\|_{\mathcal{H}_1\to\mathcal{H}_2}\leq\max\{s_j(K)\vert j\in\mathbb{N}\}$, with equality if (and only if) $u=e_{j_0}$ where $\max\{s_j(K)\vert j\in\mathbb{N}\}=s_{j_0}$ -- the maximum is attained as the eigenvalues of the compact operator $K$ remain in a compact neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By the $\otimes$ notation you mean $ e_{j} \otimes f_{j} = < e_{j}, \dot > f_{j}$ right? And also in the end if I substitute the sum from (*) I am not sure how the calculation leads to the max. Could you elaborate on that? Would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @craaaft Yes this is the definition of the Hilbert tensor product $\otimes$. I have added some details for the last computation. Also, there were some mistakes in the notations as in the decomposition of $K^*K$, I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: @craaaft Most welcome!

Comment: Maybe on thing I still don't understand is why the infinite sum of the singular values squared (when setting $u = e_{j}$) is equal to the maximum of the singular values?

Comment: @craaaft This is because in $K$, you only take the $s_{j_0}(K)$ corresponding to the maximum of the singular values because of the projection onto the vector space generated by $e_{j_0}$ (that is, $\langle e_j,e_{j_0}\rangle=\delta_{j,j_0}$ selects the index $j_0$ in the infinite sum).

Comment: If I choose such $j_{0}$, what guarantees me that the corresponding singular value is the maximum? Sorry if I misunderstand something.

Comment: @craaaft You FIRST choose $j_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $s_{j_0}(K)$ is the largest singular value (there is a largest singular value, so you fix the index $j_0$ from there). You let THEN $u:=e_{j_0}$ to attain the equality.

Comment: I see, I guess i have trouble to see that if I choose the specific singular value at $j_{0}$ then why should $u$ be a element from the orthonormal system and not something else.

Comment: @craaaft Notice that the proof goes in two steps: in the first general computation of $\|Ku\|_{\mathcal{H}_2}^2=\langle K^*Ku,u\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_1}$, you do not choose anything, $u$ there is general with $\|u\|_{\mathcal{H}_1}=1$. This yields the inequality $\|K\|_{\mathcal{H}_1\to\mathcal{H}_2}\leq\max\{s_j(K)\vert k\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Then, to show the equality, you choose a particular $u$: you choose $j_0$ such that $s_{j_0}(K)=\max\{s_j(K)\vert k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and let $u:=e_{j_0}$.

Comment: Aha, I think I got it now. Thanks for the patience!

Comment: @craaaft Most welcome! Please do not hesitate to ask me if something is not clear!